# Python 3.8 tensorflow error, ImportError: Could not find the DLL(s) 'msvcp140_1.dll'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Quiero hacer un sistema de login con reconocimiento facial y para eso estoy utilizando la librería "mtcnn", y al instalarla me pide que instale tensorflow, una vez instalado hice la primera parte del código que solo abre una ventana de tkinter pero me dice un error gigante, el error no es por el código si no por la librería tensorflow, lo que hice fue instalar el dll de la pagina oficial de dllS, el [msvcp140_1.dll], intente meterlo en estos lugares:

"C:\Users\Yo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38",

"C:\Users\Yo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts", "

"C:\Users\Yo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\DLLs"

En uno de esos es donde se supone que se pone en uno de esos directorios, pero me da el mismo error, dice que instale Microsoft C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019 pero la verdad no quiero instalar un solo programa entero que no usaré solo por la librería, donde se coloca el archivo .dll correctamente, necesito la libreria urgentemente

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yo\OneDrive\Desktop\login.py", line 5, in <module>
    from mtcnn import MTCNN #pip install mtcnn/pip install  tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Yo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mtcnn\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from mtcnn.mtcnn import MTCNN
  File "C:\Users\Yo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mtcnn\mtcnn.py", line 37, in <module>
    from mtcnn.network.factory import NetworkFactory
  File "C:\Users\Yo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mtcnn\network\factory.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, PReLU, Flatten, Softmax
  File "C:\Users\Yo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\Yo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "C:\Users\Yo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
  File "C:\Users\Yo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Yo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    self_check.preload_check()
  File "C:\Users\Yo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 54, in preload_check
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Could not find the DLL(s) 'msvcp140_1.dll'. TensorFlow requires that these DLLs be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. You may install these DLLs by downloading "Microsoft C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019" for your platform from this URL: https://support.microsoft.com/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads
```

Answer (score 0):

**La solución** a tu problema es realizar las instalaciones que te piden, ya que son **necesarias** para el funcionamiento de `Tensorflow`, es decir, si no las instalas `Tensorflow` no funcionara.

`Tensorflow` es una librería bastante compleja ya que esta escrita en varios lenguajes de programación, hace funcionar a la CPU y también a la GPU, se utiliza en producción en distintos lenguajes, Python, Java, R.

A donde te quiero llevar es que la complejidad de la librería es muy muy alta, por tanto querer quitar partes de la librería o requerimientos necesarios, es muy  complejo, puesto que no sabes como todo esta conectado.